# How to calculate execution time of a stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, time

If I have this script that creates and calls a procedure:

```
 SET profiling = 1;


 /*Create procedure */
DELIMITER ++
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS newproc++

CREATE PROCEDURE newproc()
       BEGIN
DECLARE x  INT;
SET x = 1;

WHILE x < 500 DO  

   SELECT * FROM tableName
   WHERE survived = 1
   ORDER BY class ;

   SET x = x + 1;
END WHILE;

END
++   
DELIMITER ;

/*Call procedure */
CALL newproc();


SHOW PROFILES;
```

**SHOW PROFILES** displays the individual execution time of each of the 500 queries.

But how I can display the **total execution time** of **all** the queries combined(e.i. the execution time of the newproc() procedure)?

Answer (score 0):

Event timings using the intervals `YEAR, QUARTER, MONTH`, and `YEAR_MONTH` are resolved in months; those using any other interval are resolved in seconds. There is no way to cause events scheduled to occur at the same second to execute in a given order. In addition—due to rounding, the nature of threaded applications, and the fact that a nonzero length of time is required to create events and to signal their execution—events may be delayed by as much as 1 or 2 seconds. However, the time shown in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS` table's `LAST_EXECUTED` column or the `mysql.event` table's `last_executed` column is always accurate to within one second of the actual event execution time.

Refer [this page.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)